# module_init not showing the printk that I want it to

Tags: c, linux, module, terminal, kernel

I am trying to make my module display a `printk`. I'm new to this so I might have some programming errors. This is my module C file:

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

asmlinkage long sys_mycall(int myid, char* firstname)
{
    printk ("Hello, %s! \n sys_mycall called from process %d with  ID %d. \n",
        firstname, current->id, myid);

    return 0;
}

static int my_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}

static int my_exit(void)
{
    printk("Goodbye!");
    return 0;
}

module_init(sys_mycall);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

First thing is that I don't know how the arrow pointer exactly works so I usually omit it from the `printk` so it compiles perfectly. If someone can give me a link or something on how to understand it I would really appreciate it.

When I insert it using `insmod` in the terminal and then display the message using `dmesg` I get the message by the `module_init` calling the `sys_mycall` but I cannot add any arguments to it and it displays the message but it doesn't show anything for `firstname` or for `myid`.

Comment: What is the type of `current`? Why is it not declared in `sys_mycall`? Same question for `pantherid`?

Comment: @EitanT I don't know how the whole `current->id` works

Comment: `current` points to a struct of some kind, and `id` is a field in that struct. `current->id` refers to that field. You are using `current->id` and not `current.id` because `current` is a pointer. You should probably read [this](http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=282) before you proceed with your coding.

Comment: Also note that `current` is not declared anywhere in your function. My guess is that you copy-pasted the `printk` line from somewhere and forgot to copy the matching declaration... (the same applies to `pantherid`, whatever it is).

Comment: current is always defined in the kernel, it points to the current task that is running.

Comment: what fill the function params? AFAIK, init of module doesn't get parameters (there is another way to add them)

Comment: yes, current points to the current process that is running but then, I don't get how it's related to the id. Should it change everytime the message is displayed in the terminal?

Comment: @roni can you please elaborate with the other way to add them?

Comment: see http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html for the params.

Comment: @roni thanks for the info about the `current` macro, I never worked with the Linux kernel.

Comment: current is a pointer (in fact it is a macro, but you treat it as a pointer). every time the kernel switch tasks, the current is changed and points to the struct of the new task. since when you load module from user space you start a process you will see a different id each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem that module init expect no parameters in the function, it must be void (you can add them in a different way), so basically your function is called with garbage that is currently in the stack, which might be anything but it probably zero as otherwise your kernel will crash.

what do you want to print? I understand current->id, but no the others.

Comment: just like the printk says it just a regular greeting message saying your name, the current process where the method is being called from (current->id), and then an employee id

Comment: the id and name can be anything

Comment: ok, so you find at http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html how to add parameters to module. after you define it you run inmod myname="name" myid=2, it is written very clearly in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have no log level specified, so I suspect it's being filtered out as below the threshold.  Stick a KERN_WARNING in front of your format string and verify that it prints.  Message without a log level are interpreted at CONFIG_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL from your .config file.