# how does current->pid work for linux?

Tags: c, linux, process

Do I need to include a library? 
Can anyone please elaborate in it?

I know is used to get the process id of the current task where is being called from

But I want to printk something with current->pid

`printk("My current process id/pid is %d\n", current->pid);`

...and is giving me an error

`error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`

Comment: what version of linux are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `#include <linux/sched.h>`. That's where `task_struct` is declared.

Comment: +1 I think you actually answered the question, as opposed to me.

Comment: @RobI Thanks. I'm not entirely sure either, but I think the question is about kernel programming, given the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837446/module-init-not-showing-the-printk-that-i-want-it-to).

Comment: `#include <linux/kernel.h>` is needed as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your code should work. You are probably missing some header.

`current` is a per-cpu variable defined in `linux/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h` (all the code is for the case of x86):

```
DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task);
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
    return percpu_read_stable(current_task);
}
#define current get_current()
```

`current` points to the task running on a CPU at a given moment. Its type is `struct task_struct` and it is defined in `linux/include/linux/sched.h`:

```
struct task_struct {
    ...
    pid_t pid;   // process identifier
    pid_t tgid;  // process thread group id
    ...
};
```

You can browse the code for these files in the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/):

- [current.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h)
- [sched.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4/include/linux/sched.h)

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for the [getpid()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpid.2.html) system call.  I don't know what `current` is though.